# sklearn FutureWarning message when running a CNN model

Tags: scikit-learn, error-handling

When I run my model, I am receiving the following error message:

```
FutureWarning: Pass classes=[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24], y=[20 16  4 ...  2  2  2] as keyword args. From version 0.25 passing these as positional arguments will result in an error
  FutureWarning)
```

I am assuming I need to pass them as keyword args. I am new to the Sklearn library and wondered if anyone has had experience removing this warning before or passing arguments as keyword args? I can ignore the warning, but I don't think that would be best.

Comment: As the warning says, not passing the classes and y values using keyword arguments will give an error in a newer version of scikit-learn. Simply using keyword arguments should stop this error from showing.